# Constructing an object in switch statement

Tags: c++, memory

So I have a piece of code, that will create an array object written by myself. In a switch statement my lecturer will choose whether he wants to create an array by himself, or to generate a random one. My switch statement looks liketo this:

```
#include "MyArray.h"


MyArray::MyArray(): n(0)
{
} 

MyArray::MyArray(int *t, int n) : n(n), this->t(new int[n])
{   
    memcpy(this->t, t, n * sizeof(int));
}

int MyArray::size() const
{
    return n;
}

int *MyArray::get() const
{
    return this->t;
}

MyArray::~MyArray()
{
    std::cout << "DESTRUCTING" << '\n';
    delete[] t;
}

MyArray::MyArray(const MyArray & obj)
{
    n = obj.n;
    t = new int[obj.n];
    memcpy(t, obj.t, obj.n * sizeof(int));
}

MyArray& MyArray::operator=(const MyArray& obj)
{
    if (this != &obj)
    {
        delete[] t;
        n = obj.n;
        t = new int[obj.n];
        for (int i = 0; i<obj.n; i++)
            t[i] = obj.t[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Didn't want to post the whole code, cause it wouldn't be good to read, I only shown the object relevant parts. So the question finally is, how to make it work without a memory leaks?

Comment: I suggest you start by reading about [the rule of three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: `(this->t = new int and memcpy, this->n = n)` -- `(simply delete t[])` -- Why did you write fake code, when the real code is probably just a few characters more than the fake code you posted?

Comment: *Didn't want to post the whole code, cause it wouldn't be good to read,* Try to create a [mcve]. Some times that itself gives you enough insight to solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: _so I want it to live as long as I am in this loop_ ...then you have to create your array object `ar` before the loop, not inside. But it's hard to tell without seeing the code of that loop. I also suggest using `std::vector` instead of rolling your own dynamic arrray.

Comment: Also, the `switch` statement first declares a `MyArray` instance that is default constructed (no arguments), yet your fake code is shown in the constructor for `MyArray` that takes two arguments, not the default `MyArray` constructor.  So even your attempt of "simplifying" the code is not showing us anything.

Comment: First of all, cannot use anything from `std::`. Second of all, updated the code. @PaulMcKenzie, yes, I know what are you talking about. I had to use default constructor, because the array has to be available for every `case` block of code. I don't argue because I don't know if it can be done better, if it does, I'll be more than happy to know how

Comment: @FrynioS -- With the code posted, this simple 1 line program causes undefined behavior: `{MyArray arr;}` -- The reason is that you failed to initialize your pointer in the default constructor to `nullptr`, and the destructor will attempt to call `delete[]` on the uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, jesus, sometimes when I review code, that I wrote, day after I feel like a total retard. Of course that was the issue! Thanks, my friend, you saved a lot of my time :D